# How to load sql dump in a containerized django docker which depends on postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I am running a Django container on docker which depends on Postgres. Now the issue is, when I try to load the postgresql

```
docker-compose up
cat /tmp/dump.sql |  sudo docker exec -i <container_id> psql -U <user> -d <database_name>
```

This imports the first few tables and gives me a lot of errors on the terminal

An example

```
constraint "table_id" for relation "table_name" already exists
```

Another example

```
null value in column "column_name" violates not-null constraint
```

Another one

```
insert or update on table "table_1" violates foreign key constraint "table_id"
```

I wanted to know is this even the right way to import this data. Plus I cant seem to drop the database as it is already being used by django.

**Note:**
I tried with volumes where I imported the db with postgresql. But everytime I run django, the database gets reset. I am guessing it has something to do with the migrations, but I can't touch that part.

Comment: You might have trouble restoring a dump like this if your application container automatically runs migrations as part of its startup sequence.  Does it work to start only the database, then run the restore, then start the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was being caused because the sql dump was trying to overwrite existing db. A quick solution if you are on dev would be to

`docker volume rm <volume_name>`.

And then run the `cat ...` command

Comment: Dropping the volume is a bit drastic. The null errors may also indicates that it's SQL file is not a valid backup or only a partial one. Dropping the volume will just loose data. Better to create a new database in the same cluster, restore from the backup, bind the service to the new database changing the configuration. In this case no data are destroyed and there is a way to fallback if the backup is not plenty.

Comment: Makes sense. In my case the data is irrelevant and I needed a quick fix to get my dev env back on track.

Comment: Not sure the time spared worth it. The proposal is also quick one with no data loss and no volume manipulations until you recover.